# ArrayList cast to PriorityQueue + java

Tags: java

I am having this problem that I had used Arraylist in my entire program up till now and now I need its functioning to be that of priority queue too.

So I did the obvious that seemed to me and casted it like `PriorityQueue z  = (PriorityQueue) x`
where x was arraylist.

At runtime this gave an error that this is not possible.

Is there any simple way to make this work. I can't change entire array list as a priority queue since then I'll have to update all the functions used.....

Should I add item each time from arraylist to a new priority queue or is there a better method...

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue();
pq.addAll(x);
```

Comment: Why am i getting the error that 'Vertex cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable' where x is List of Vertex

Comment: @user506710 You are trying to make a priority queue out of items that don't implement comparable. Edit: In other words, Java has no way to say which Vertex is smaller or larger than another, because it doesn't implement the Comparable interface. For more details, look here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: hopefully that pq.addAll should take O(n), instead of n*log(n) if we add items one by one to pq.

Answer (score 0):

A priority queue has a lot of extra code associated with it to ensure that the items within the priority queue are ordered by priority.  An array list has none of that code, so you can't just cast it into a priority queue.

Generally things can be upcast safely, but you're trying to downcast something here.  You can't do it, as there's no assurance that the array list is ordered with any kind of priority.  Nor are the underlying data structures implementing the two internally guaranteed to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way.  An `ArrayList` implements `List` interface, but not the `Queue`.

Creating a new queue from the list contents is probably simplest.

If you know the content is sorted by priority and you need to be really efficient, try wrapping it with a `Queue` class backed by your `ArrayList` if you need a queue-like object in one place, but are using `List`s for good reasons elsewhere.